# PHP openssl_encrypt c# implementation

Tags: c#, encryption, php-openssl

I am developing an integration in C# which syncs Office365 distribution lists to Sendy (sendy.co), written in PHP.

In the PHP application some ID's are being encrypted and I want to achieve the same in C# so that I can communicate using their API without having to look up the 'secret' ID.

This is the code in PHP (I replaced the password) in their application that calculates these ID's:

```
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($in, 'AES-256-CBC', 'API_KEY', 0, 'SECRET_PASSWORD');
$encrypted = str_replace('/', '892', $encrypted);
$encrypted = str_replace('+', '763', $encrypted);
$encrypted = str_replace('=', '', $encrypted);
```

I overcame this 'issue' by hosting the PHP script somewhere and calling it from my C# application, but I want to make it opensource so I would like this to be integrated in the application.

I suppose I would have to start with .NET's `AesCryptoServiceProvider`, but I don't seem to be able to get it right (I get exceptions about the key length and stuff).

So far I tried this:

```
    public static string Execute()
    {
        // openssl_encrypt ( string $data , string $method , string $password [, int $options = 0 [, string $iv = "" ]] )
        var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.KeySize = 256;

        // Fixed password in code
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("FIXED PASSWORD");
        // API = IV
        aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SENDY API KEY");

        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        // Trying to encrypt "36" in this case
        byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("36");

        // Actual encryption
        using (var encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);

            // Convert byte array to Base64 strings
            return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
        }
    }
```

However this throws an exception saying the IV doesn't match the block size of the algorithm.

I suppose the openssl_encrypt method in PHP derivatives the actual IV from the given API KEY in the sample (so the $password parameter), but I can't find much documentation on it to be able to achieve the same in C#.

Comment: The codes, we needs the codes. SO is not about writing your code, it is about helping you with code. Add you attempted code along with detailed problems and debugging output.

Comment: There are better ways to deal with troublesome characters in Base64, what you have will break. Both '892' and '763' can be valid Base64 sequences. Typically one just URL encoded Base64 if necessary. Using a constant iv is a bad idea and insecure.

Comment: Yes I can understand that the PHP code isn't good practice but I didn't write it and it's not my application, I just need to achieve the same in PHP.
I deleted my "trying" code, I'll try again and update my question with my attempted code, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

The size of the iv must be equal to the block size which for AES is 16-bytes, `"SENDY API KEY"` is only 13-bytes.

The iv should be a different random value for each encryption, just prepend it to the encrypted data for use during decryption.

Next you have specified a key size of 256-bits but the key `"FIXED PASSWORD"` is only 14-bytes, make them the same, 128, 192 or 256 bits (16, 24 or 32 bytes). There is no need to use a key over 128-bits.

A password should not be used directly for a key, the key should be derived from the password with a function such as PBKFD2.

AES is a block cipher and it's. Input needs to be a multiple of the block size in length. To accomplish this padding of the input is needed. Typically PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding is used, it is probably the default for OpenSSL. The encryption/decryptions should automatically add/remove this padding. But this does mean that the encrypted data length will be from 1-byte to 16-bytes longer than the input. e.g. If you encrypt `"36"` the output length will be 16-bytes.

Getting all this together correctly can be difficult to get correct, consider using an overall solution such as [RNCryptor-php](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-php) or [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption)